# ASP.NET MVC jsonPropertyName in controller's parameter is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.8

I have an ASP.NET MVC controller that accepts a class as a parameter

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(MyClass model)
{
    // ... codes here
}
```

The content of `MyClass` is

```
public class MyClass 
{
    [JsonPropertyName("MyCustomJsonProperty")]
    public string myProperty { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

But when I post this to the controller's action

```
{
    "MyCustomJsonProperty": 123
    "property1": 1,
    "property2": 2,
}
```

The value I get in the controller is null, but the other properties have data. I've tried adding `[JsonProperty("BatchNumber")]` attribute to `myProperty`, but it is still null.

How do I properly pass my data in controller?

Comment: Are your other properties decorated with JsonPropertyName? I have always assumed that parameter binding at the controller level was using reflection on the actual property name, does it bind if you use "myProperty" on the model you pass in? I thought JsonPropertyName was specific to functionality within the System.Text.Json namespace

Comment: Make sure the input json values match the datatypes that you have defined in your class. For example, you have defined mycustomjsonproperty as a string but are passing an int.

Answer (score 1):

`JsonPropertyName` (highly likely) comes from `System.Text.Json` which is used by default in modern ASP.NET Core. Since it seems that you are using classic ASP.NET with .NET Framework it will not work out of the box. The easiest option would be to just rename the property in the model or create one with proper naming. Other option is to write your own `ModelBinder` which will consider the used attributes.